# MATLAB integration of 2x2 system

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math, symbolic-integration

I got the following matrice:

[image]

which I want to integrate with MATLAB. The obvious solution would be:

[image]

which is exactly what I am trying to achieve. I am using symbolic calculation for this. (example only for one variable)

```
syms aiso w w1 w2
```

With the matrice definition

```
A = [1/2/aiso 1/2; -1/2/aiso 1/2];
```

Now I integrate symbolically via

```
A = int(A,w);
```

Which gives me the result

```
A = [ w*1/(2*aiso), w*1/2; -w*1/(2*aiso), w*1/2]
```

That is obviously right but since I only used one symbolic variable that's not quite the case I need. I need the solution from above, which is stated in vector notation on the second picture and which should look like this in MATLAB:

```
A = [ (w1)*1/(2*aiso) + (w2)*1/2; (w1)*1/(2*aiso) - (w2)1/2]
```

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: You may want to create `w` as a symbolic vector `w = sym('w', [2,1])` or integrate w.r.t `[w1;w2]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this isn't working for me. When I try int(dA,[w1 w2]), MATLAB interprets it as an integration interval with lower and upper border. Any other ideas maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate each component of the matrix `dA` to get `A`:

```
syms aiso w w1 w2
dA = [1/2/aiso 1/2; -1/2/aiso 1/2];
A = [int(dA(1,1),w1)+int(dA(1,2),w2) int(dA(2,1),w1)+int(dA(2,2),w2)]
disp(A)
```

Output:

```
[ w2/2 + w1/(2*aiso), w2/2 - w1/(2*aiso)]
```

It is not elegant but it works.

Comment: This works grat for this special case. But I plan to advance to more sophisticated entries like

Comment: Thank you - I just tried it!This works great for this special case, where integration equal a simple multiplication with the vector w. But I finally plan to andvance towards matrices with entries containing dependencies like dA(1,1) = w2*w1/aiso and dA(1,2) = w1^2*w2/2; for example. So maybe there's another more general way. (?)

Comment: @WilliamD. Currently, I can only come out of this way. I will update my answer once I know more general way.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!